# How to index elements of list in a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': ['Hello, I have some text.</p> I would like to split it into sentences. </p> However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.</p> I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.',
                       'Hello, I have some text.</p> I would like to split it into sentences. </p> However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.</p> I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.',
                       'Hello, I have some text.</p> I would like to split it into sentences. </p> However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.</p> I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.']})
```

What I want to do is, first, splitting the dataframe and, then, converting the list into a dataframe and create a column that keep track of how many sentences belong to a text.

To split the text I do:

```
df.Text.str.split('</p>')

df.Text.str.split('</p>')[0]
```

As you can see, every element in the original dataframe contains the 4 sentences which I split. I now want to create a dataframe as the the following one:

```
ID    Text

1.1   Hello, I have some text.
1.2  I would like to split it into sentences. 
1.3  However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.
1.4  I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.
2.1  Hello, I have some text.
2.2  I would like to split it into sentences. 
2.3  However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.
2.4 I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.
3.1  Hello, I have some text.
3.2  I would like to split it into sentences. 
3.3 However, when it comes to splitting I want sentences to be indexed so that I can re-join them correctly.
3.4 I also need to convert lists in df which is tricky.
```

Can anyone help me do it?

Thanks!

PS. In the real example, the sentences are not evenly split as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to create new rows, and finally rework the index:

```
df2 = (df.assign(Text=df['Text'].str.split('</p>'))
         .explode('Text')
       )

idx = df2.index.to_series().add(1).astype(str)
idx2 = idx.groupby(idx).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

df2.index = idx+'.'+idx2
```

output:

```
                                                  Text
1.1                           Hello, I have some text.
1.2          I would like to split it into sentences. 
1.3   However, when it comes to splitting I want se...
1.4   I also need to convert lists in df which is t...
2.1                           Hello, I have some text.
2.2          I would like to split it into sentences. 
2.3   However, when it comes to splitting I want se...
2.4   I also need to convert lists in df which is t...
3.1                           Hello, I have some text.
3.2          I would like to split it into sentences. 
3.3   However, when it comes to splitting I want se...
3.4   I also need to convert lists in df which is t...
```